# UWP c++ winrt app shows SHGDNF is unidentified in ShObjldl_core.h

Tags: desktop-bridge, c++-winrt

I'm moving a c# .netcore application to UWP desktop bridge. I'm able to deploy and build the app, but when adding the c++ winrt component I get an error indicating SHGDNF is unidentified in ShObjldl_core.h below is pch.cpp

```c
`#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>

#include <tchar.h>

#include <Unknwn.h>

#include <winrt/base.h>

#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <pathcch.h>

#include <ShlGuid.h>

#include <ShObjIdl_core.h>

#include <ShlObj_core.h>

#include <cfapi.h>

#include <ntstatus.h>

#include <sddl.h>

#include <winrt\windows.storage.provider.h>

#include <winrt\Windows.Security.Cryptography.h>

#include <ppltasks.h>

#include <strsafe.h>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could press **F12** over `ShObjIdl_core.h` to view the document, and you will see there is a `#if` statement `#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)` which says the header file is usable for **Desktop Win32** apps(but not store apps). A C++/Winrt component project is not a Win32 app, therefore, `ShObjIdl_core.h` header could not be used in the project.

Comment: is there another header file I can reference?

Comment: We could not find one header who could replace the ShlObj_core.h header. If just the ShlObj_core.h header couldn’t be used in you scenario, you could write your needed DWORD from the header to replace it.
For example:
`enum _SHGDNF
    {
        SHGDN_NORMAL    = 0,
        SHGDN_INFOLDER  = 0x1,
        SHGDN_FOREDITING    = 0x1000,
        SHGDN_FORADDRESSBAR = 0x4000,
        SHGDN_FORPARSING    = 0x8000
    } ;
typedef DWORD SHGDNF;
`

Comment: If your problem is resolved, it is better if you could mark the answer so that poeple with the same problems could find a solution quickly.